# Lyapunov exponent of "real life"

Tags: chaos-theory, complex-systems

Today I simply forgot watching soccer WM on TV, and promptly my national team lost. Assume there is a meaningful alternative universe where I turned on the TV *(quantum and relativity theorists already might protest - just assume it)* and nothing else changed at the time of kick-off. A ripple of changes now will propagate with lightspeed. I assume weather will show the fastest effects, but how fast will it take that a macroscopic event like a soccer game shows visible changes? (This surely can't be computed, but a Fermi style estimation would completely satisfy me.)

Or more general: How fast does a tiny human action change the vicinity macroscopically due to the chaos butterfly effect?

Comment: Once you assume one impossible thing, all bets are off. You're basically just asking for someone to finish your fictional story.

Comment: I think https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/ might be a better home for this question.

Comment: @stafusa Doesn't seem like an issue if there are a lot of physics people there. Are there?

Comment: Forgive my lack of citing of sources, but I do remember reading a book on chaos theory which suggested that a butterfly flapping its wings in Japan would generate differences sufficiently great that, within a month, one would not be able to predict whether it would rain or shine over New York.  That being said, humans are **far** more interconnected these days.  Just a tweet can set things in motion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're asking about "[Lyapunov time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_time)", which gives you the time scale for chaos to be noticeable. For the weather [it's](http://fy.chalmers.se/%7Ef99krgu/dynsys/DynSysLecture10.pdf) on the order of days, perhaps two weeks tops.

Wikipedia has a nice table with such values:

| System | Lyapunov time |
| --- | --- |
| Solar System | 5 million years |
| Pluto's orbit | 20 million years |
| Obliquity of Mars | 1–5 million years |
| Orbit of 36 Atalante | 4,000 years |
| Rotation of Hyperion | 36 days |
| Chemical chaotic oscillations | 5.4 minutes |
| Hydrodynamic chaotic oscillations | 2 seconds |
| 1 cm3 of argon at room temperature | 3.7×10−11 seconds |
| 1 cm3 of argon at triple point (84 K, 69 kPa) | 3.7×10−16 seconds |

As for the OP's title question (the LE of "life"), the trouble is that this disproportionate effect that chaos allow tiny changes to have means that large changes can take place — but not that *everything* is different because something tiny is different.

And especially in such a large system (essentially the whole world) not everything is strongly connected and what is going on in some subsystems, chaotic or not, is unlikely to meaningfully affect the larger world. Also, parts of it are certainly not chaotic (most of what we build, for instance, is linear or intended to at least be predictable). And lastly, many connections are not reciprocal — the actions of a given soccer team may affect some millions of people, but one of them forgetting to watch a soccer game will in most cases have precisely zero influence on the team.

Comment: Ah, this I could have found myself if searching longer :-) (Unfortunately, there is no good way to experimentally execute my thought experiment even approximately, see critics above, but it suffices as answer.)

Comment: @HaukeReddmann I actually had not addressed you main question directly enough, I hope to have fixed this now (see updated answer). The bottom line is: you'll have a very hard time finding a parallel universe where Germany(?) won the match _because_ you remembered to watch the game. :-)